# Как сделать так, чтобы программа последовательно проверяла слова на наличие и удаляла их из строки?

Tags: java, строки

Алгоритм примерно такой:
Допустим у нас есть строка:
Строка: "Бутылка Маша Таня пенёк Маша"
удалить слово "бутылка", если оно есть
затем удалить слово "Маша", если оно есть(только то слово, которое попалось первым)
удалить слово "пенёк", если оно есть
удалить слово "Маша", если оно есть
То есть программа должна удалять заданное одно слово, если оно есть, а не все подобные слова сразу(в данном случае не все слова Маша сразу)

Comment: Есть какие наработки ? Или вы про идею самой реализации спрашиваете ?

Comment: Gin Tasan, про идею реализации, я знаю, как удалить все одинаковые слова, но не знаю, как удалить только одно из них

Comment: Кстити говоря, если со строками работаете и с их изменением, используйте StringBuilder или , по необходимости , StringBuffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод `String.replaceFirst()` заменяет только первый найденный результат:

```
text = text.replaceFirst("Маша", "");
```

Comment: До меня слегка не доходит, text это имя переменной? Если да, то у меня этот вариант почему-то не срабатывает

Comment: Потому что надо присвоить результат выполнения другой переменной. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: спасибо большое!