# Как сделать так, чтобы программа поочерёдно проверяла наличие определённых сочетания букв в строке, а затем удаляла их?

Tags: java, строки

Допустим у меня есть строка:
String str = "СашалюбитМашуСашавася";
мне нужно сделать так, чтобы программа, к примеру, проверяла сначала начало строки на наличие одного из слов "любит", "Саша", "Машу" и при нахождении его (любого из этих слов) удаляла, затем всё повторялось, пока все выбранные слова не будут удалены
То есть в данном примере:

```
строка = "СашалюбитМашуСашавася";
затем строка = "любитМашуСашавася";
затем строка = "МашуСашавася";
затем строка = "Сашавася";
затем строка = "вася"; // слова вася в списке нет, поэтому программа его не удаляет
```

Comment: Чем этот вопрос отличается от предыдущего? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/977332/282277

Comment: Эникейщик, тем, что в данном случае программа должна удалять первое попавшееся слово из списка(то есть любое слово, из приведённого списка, которое оказалось в строке раньше остальных слов из списка), а не просто одно слово, независимо от его позиции, как это было в прошлый раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String sentence = "СашалюбитМашуСашавася";

        while (true) {
            sentence = removeWord(sentence, "любит", "Саша", "Машу");
            if (sentence == null) break;
            System.out.println(sentence);
        }

    }

    private static String removeWord(String sentence, String... words) {
        for (String word : words) {
            if (sentence.indexOf(word) == 0) 
                return sentence.substring(word.length(), sentence.length());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Можно так... Способов много на самом деле

Comment: весьма странный код. почему нельзя вместо return сразу выводить строку и сократить все в два раза, зачем этот первый цикл вообще ... не говоря уже о том, что такое решение в стиле какого то бейсика с попыткой симулировать многострадальный goto. на java за такое руки отрывают :)